# why the type of *p is int after (const int* p) but can not change its value?

Tags: c++, constants, typeid

here is my code

```
    int age = 36;
    const int* p = &age;

    cout << typeid(age).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(p).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(*p).name() << endl;
```

the result is `int`,`int const *`,`int`. I am confused about the type of `*p` is `int` . why not we change the value of `*p`.

```
    *(&age) += 1;
    *p += 1;
```

`p`is `int const *`, why not `const int*` ? `*p` should be the same of `age` `*(&age)`, but can not apply about `+=` operation.

even more

```
    int* const q = &age;
    cout << typeid(q).name << endl;
    cout << typeid(*q).name << endl;
```

it would rase error when use `typeid()`,why this happened?

Comment: In
```int* const q = &age; cout << typeid(q).name << endl; cout << typeid(*q).name << endl; ```
 you missing () after ```.name```

Comment: oh, yes, I missed them. :) the result is ```int * ``` and ```int``` no relation of const

Comment: Might want to use [std::is_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const) for your checks.

Comment: It seems to me that your experiment skipped a step. Did you try a version where the types are more consistent, as in starting with `const int age = 36;` instead of merely `int age = 36;`? If you haven't looked at `typeid(const int).name()`, it's a bit premature to throw pointers into the mix and assume they changed the outcome. Start simple.

Answer (score 4):

Because [typeid operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) ignores cv-qualifiers, so you got `int` intead of `const int`.

> In all cases, top-level cv-qualifiers are ignored by typeid (that is, `typeid(const T) == typeid(T)`).

This is just the special behavior of `typeid`; what `*p` returns is still `const`, you can't modify on it directly. (That's the point we use pointer to const instead of pointer to non-const.)

Given `int* const q`, `const` is qualifed on the pointer, i.e. it's a top-level qualifier, then `typeid(q)` ignores `const` and gives `int*`.

BTW: `int const *` is same as `const int*`.